# lightweight, polyglot alternative to JMX?

Tags: java, c++, c, real-time, jmx

I have a soft real-time application project that needs extensive monitoring. 
JMX would seem well suited for that task, except that this application project is c++-based.

Are there any lightweight alternatives to JMX (with a  c/c++ supporting library) that are minimally invasive for the monitored application?

(SNMP seems really overkill for my needs)

Comment: It is? Thought JMX was Java http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html

Comment: So you are looking for a c++ JMX endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if SNMP would seem overkill for your application it still may be your best bet. Net SNMP is not hard to use and it has a well known standard for monitoring applications.

Some other alternatives would be:

**rsyslog**
The problem you may experience with this one though is that it may be harder to integrate it into the monitoring application. But it has a well known standard and may be worth a shot.

**JunC++ion**
It has a nice interface for C++ but from my experience it can be a bit unstable. In embedded mode it also uses a bit more memory which may not be what you want.

Comment: I'd support an SNMP choice for its simplicity and genericity, besides being a standard which means community support and loads of information online.

Answer (score 0):

Try Nagios: http://www.nagios.org/about/overview/